# TCP/IP client read/write data, windows 10 app

Tags: c#, xaml, tcp-ip, uwp

Привет всем. Делаю проект "Arduino + windows 10 app". У меня МК соединяется с приложением через WiFi . Хочу написать приложение для общения МК программе . МК выступает в роли сервера , программа - клиент. У меня получается соединиться с устройством , передать данные , но принять он не может. На сколько я понял , неправильно установлено поток входа.
П.С. Этот пример я уже рассматривал , не помогло (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket).
Может ктото знает, имеет похожую программу, как ета
[image: SocketTest v3.0]

Моя программа:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    StreamSocket _socket;
    HostName _hostName;
    DataWriter writer;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _socket = new StreamSocket();
    }
    private async void connectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        #region _check_parameters
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName_Box.Text))
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Set the Host Name !!!\n";
            return;
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceName_Box.Text))
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Set the Service Name !!!\n";
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            _hostName = new HostName(hostName_Box.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Invalid Host Name !!!\n";
            return;
        }
        #endregion
        // If necessary, tweak the socket's control options before carrying out the connect operation.
        // Refer to the StreamSocketControl class' MSDN documentation for the full list of control options.
        _socket.Control.KeepAlive = false;
        try
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "Connecting...\n";
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(_hostName, serviceName_Box.Text);
            _statusBar.Text += "Connected\n";

            // go to send mode
            connectButton.Content = "Send";
            connectButton.Click -= connectButton_Click;
            connectButton.Click += send_Data;
            hostName_Box.PlaceholderText = "data to send";
            hostName_Box.Text = "";
            writer = new DataWriter(_socket.OutputStream);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Connect failed with error:\n" + exception.Message + "\n";
        }
    }
    private async void read_data()
    {
        DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(_socket.InputStream);
        dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        try
        {
            await dataReader.LoadAsync(5);
            string s;
            uint length;
            length = dataReader.ReadUInt32();
            s = dataReader.ReadString(length);
            _statusBar.Text += "Read successful\n" + s + "\n";
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Fail to load dada !!!\n" +
                exception.Message + "\n";
        }
    }

    private async void send_Data(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName_Box.Text))
        {
            _statusBar.Text += "Write anything\n";
            return;
        }
        if(hostName_Box.Text == "read")
        {
            try
            {
                hostName_Box.Text = "";
                read_data();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Reading data failed:\n" + ex.Message + "\n";
            }
        }
        writer.WriteUInt32(writer.MeasureString(hostName_Box.Text));
        writer.WriteString(hostName_Box.Text);
        try
        {
            await writer.StoreAsync();
            _statusBar.Text += "\"" + hostName_Box.Text + "\" sent successfully\n";
            hostName_Box.Text = "";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(ex.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }
            _statusBar.Text += "[ERROR] Send failed with error:\n" + ex.Message + "\n";
        }
    }
}


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock Name="_statusBar" FontSize="24" Grid.Row="0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Name="connectButton" Content="Connect" FontSize="24" Grid.Column="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Click="connectButton_Click" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"/>
        <TextBox Name="hostName_Box" PlaceholderText="Host Name" FontSize="24" Grid.Column="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0"/>
        <TextBox Name="serviceName_Box" PlaceholderText="Service Name" FontSize="24" Grid.Column="1"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Для начала попробуйте поменять асинхронную работу с `StreamSocket`  - на синхронную, посмотрите пропадет ли проблема.

Comment: А что происходит не так с вашим примером? «Не работает» — вы же понимаете, это не описание проблемы.